# 3rd Party Dependency Install - Issue

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management, maven-exec-plugin

In my POM, I have maven-exec-plugin, which generates a Jar (say JarX). The same JarX I am installing to my local repo using install-plugin.

Also my dependency list contains details for this jar to be used in build path.  But while building the project, it fails while resolving JarX dependencies. Is there a way, I can instruct maven to skip resolving the local Jars.

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>generate-jar</id>
                <phase>clean</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>java</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>-DcompileTarget=1.8</argument>
                        <argument>-classpath</argument>
                        <classpath />
                        <argument>com.myclass.Generate</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>istall-jar-1</id>
                <phase>clean</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <file>jar file path</file>
                    <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
                    <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0</version>
                    <repositoryLayout>default</repositoryLayout>
                    <packaging>jar</packaging>
                    <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>install-file</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
<dependencies>
    <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: did you try changing the scope to "provided" or "runtime" ?

Comment: Yes. I tried with that as well but is not working...